# Update with Case statement giving error in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Below is a piece of code which I am using to update a column of an Oracle table. The select queries used are all correct and have been tested. Just that there seems to be some problem with the way case is being used. The error received is

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

on the line update table1....

```
PROCEDURE p_res( x  IN   NUMBER, y IN  DATE) IS
cursor cur1 is select ODAY, TECNO, DNO, TID, STOPNO, STIME, result1, BID, BNO from table1 where result = 0;
C1   cur1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
      FOR C1 IN cur1
          LOOP
            update table1 t1 set result1 = case select count(col1) from table2 t2 where t2.ODAY = C1.ODAY and t2.BID = C1.BID and t2.BNO = C1.BNO
                              when 0 then null
                              when 1 then col1
                              else (select col1 from (select t2.col1, abs((cast(t2.STIME as date) - cast(C1.STIME as date)))*24*60*60 as difference
                                     from table2 t2
                                     where t2.ODAY = C1.ODAY and t2.BID = C1.BID and t2.BNO = C1.BNO
                                     order by difference asc) where rownum = 1) 
                              end
              where t1.ODAY = C1.ODAY
              and t1.TECNO = C1.TECNO
              and t1.DNO = C1.DNO
              and t1.TID = C1.TID
              and t1.STOPNO = C1.STOPNO
              and t1.STIME = C1.STIME
              and t1.result1 = C1.result1;
         END LOOP;
         COMMIT;
END;
```

Can someone help in fixing this update query with case statement.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The `select count(*) ...` subquery is used as a ***scalar subquery*** in your `case` expression. As such, it should be *enclosed in parentheses* (meaning: the entire `select` subquery within `case` must be enclosed in a pair of parentheses). I didn't check the correctness of your code otherwise; see if this helps.

Comment: thanku so much. It did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be better if you could do the whole job without the loop.

Otherwise, divide et impera:

```
PROCEDURE p_res( x  IN   NUMBER, y IN  DATE) IS
  cursor cur1 is 
    select ODAY, TECNO, DNO, TID, STOPNO, STIME, result1, BID, BNO 
    from table1 
    where result = 0;
  C1   cur1%ROWTYPE;
  
  l_cnt  number;
  l_col1 table2.col1%type;
BEGIN
  FOR C1 IN cur1 LOOP
    select count(col1) 
    into l_cnt
    from table2 t2 
    where t2.ODAY = C1.ODAY 
      and t2.BID = C1.BID 
      and t2.BNO = C1.BNO;
      
    if l_cnt not in (0, 1) then  
        select col1 
        into l_col1
        from 
          (select t2.col1, 
                  abs((cast(t2.STIME as date) - cast(C1.STIME as date)))*24*60*60 as difference
           from table2 t2
           where t2.ODAY = C1.ODAY 
             and t2.BID = C1.BID 
             and t2.BNO = C1.BNO
           order by difference asc
          ) 
        where rownum = 1;
    end if;
    
    update table1 t1 set result1 = case when l_cnt = 0 then null
                                        when l_cnt = 1 then col1
                                        else l_col1
                                   end
    where t1.ODAY = C1.ODAY
      and t1.TECNO = C1.TECNO
      and t1.DNO = C1.DNO
      and t1.TID = C1.TID
      and t1.STOPNO = C1.STOPNO
      and t1.STIME = C1.STIME
      and t1.result1 = C1.result1;    
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to simplify a bit your setup. The goal is to show that you can use a single `MERGE` statement.

Assume that your *match columns* `ODAY,BID,BNO` are represented with a single unique key `KEY1` and lets ignore the constraint `result = 0`.

This gives this setup

**table1**

```
KEY1  STIME                  RESULT1
----- ------------------- ----------
a     28.01.2021 00:00:00          1
b     28.01.2021 00:00:00          1
c     28.01.2021 00:00:00          1
```

**table2**

```
KEY1  STIME                     COL1
----- ------------------- ----------
b     29.01.2021 00:00:00          2
c     27.01.2021 00:00:00          3
c     26.01.2021 00:00:00          4
c     31.01.2021 00:00:00          5
```

and the task is to update the `RESULT1` in the `table1`based on the following rules (note that this is my best re-ingeneering from your bit obfuscated example)

1. if there is *no match* on the `PK` set it to `NULL`
2. with a unique match - user the `col1`from the `table2`
3. if more records match the `key1`user the `col1`from the *closest `STIME`*

The query below joining the two tables and selecting the closest record with `row_number`analytical function, shows the expected result

```
with upd as (
select t1.key1, t2.col1,
row_number() over (partition by t1.key1 order by abs(t2.stime - t1.stime)) as rn,
t1.stime, t2.stime stime2
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2
on t1.key1 = t2.key1)
select t1.key1, t1.result1, t2.col1
from table1 t1
join upd t2
on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t2.rn = 1

KEY1     RESULT1       COL1
----- ---------- ----------
a              1           
b              1          2
c              1          3
```

The final step is to use the above query in a `merge` staement as follows

```
merge into table1 t1
using (
with upd as (
  select t1.key1, t2.col1,
    row_number() over (partition by t1.key1 order by abs(t2.stime - t1.stime)) as rn,
    t1.stime, t2.stime stime2
  from table1 t1
  left outer join table2 t2
  on t1.key1 = t2.key1)
select t1.key1, t1.result1, t2.col1
from table1 t1
join upd t2
on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t2.rn = 1) t2
on (t1.key1 = t2.key1)
when matched then
  update set t1. result1 = t2.col1
```

result is as expected

```
KEY1  STIME                  RESULT1
----- ------------------- ----------
a     28.01.2021 00:00:00           
b     28.01.2021 00:00:00          2
c     28.01.2021 00:00:00          3
```

If you have few records in your table do simple your *cursor row by row*, but with non trivial data, you'll see the performance advantage of the `SQL` approach.